# Redirect SQL connection without changing connection string

Tags: sql-server, excel

We have a single SQL server hosting 2 instances. One instance just cannot be upgraded do to legacy software. A separate project is addressing that but is over a year away. The second instance can be upgraded, but there are thousands of Excel workbooks pointing to it for reporting purposes. So in short neither connection string can be changed at this time.

Is it possible to redirect a connection from one instance to another on a second server while keeping the connection strings the same?

I need a connection from SqlServer\Instance1 to stay on that instance while SqlServer\Instance2 goes to SqlServer2\Instance2

Creative solutions may work but need to be rock solid and maintenance light.

Comment: AFAIK you can't do anything like that. Why can't you simply fix Instance2 so it is the correct version. You have a major problem in your infrastructure though. "thousands of Excel workbooks pointing to it for reporting purposes". This is just awful. Somebody should have thought about a better way than having connection strings hard coded in thousands of excel files. Maybe using a proper reporting tool or a way to use a centralized connection string. You are going to have to deal with this mess at some point.

Comment: @SeanLange You couldn't be more correct that this is flat horrible. We have tens of thousands of Excel workbooks and even more access databases out there doing similar things. This is why Shadow IT is bad. If we had a good citizen development strategy than maybe we could have avoided some of this. We can't just upgrade the instance because the point was to move it off of the 2005 server, no longer supported, and get it to a supported version. We may just have to wait until we can move the whole thing.

Comment: As for dealing with this mess in the future, I am open to any ideas on how we can address that as well. Maybe in future question. Cheers

Comment: But if it is a named instance you could uninstall the named instance from 2005 and install 2012 or whatever new version on that same machine with a named instance the same as the old one.

Comment: Understood. It is on Windows Server 2005 as well. So, upgrading one and not the other doesn't solve the issue we have.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you may be looking for has something to do with tunnels. SQL server configuration manager > SQL Native XX.X Configuration. Here, you can specify alias for instances.

Go nuts!

Please keep in mind that you might need to get your network admin involved if both DNS name are being used at the same time. A local DHCP entry can help you come up with a proof of concept. This tunnel works for instances.